# finding repeated value in objects inside an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

have an array of data for example :

`const array=[{ a:"cat"}, { a:"dog"}, { a:"dog"},{ a:"dog"}]`

iterating over the array and looking for a logic to check the value of " a " to see if it is repeated or not, if repeated return only once otherwise return

Comment: you can group them

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```js
const array=[{ a:"cat"}, { a:"dog"}, { a:"dog"},{ a:"dog"}]
const unique = array
     .map(e => e['a'])
     .map((e, i, final) => final.indexOf(e) === i && i)
     .filter(obj=> array[obj])
     .map(e => array[e].a);
     console.log(unique)
```

Comment: i am looking to retun item.a as an string like "cat", "dog"  only once for each repeated value ```array.map((item=>item.a)```

Answer (score 0):

```
let values = new Set()
newArray = array.filter(obj => {
    if(values.has(obj.a)) return false;
    values.add(obj.a);
    return true;
  });
```

I would suggest, if you intend to use `a` as basically a key, using a `Map` or `Object` instead of an `Array` to hold data.

Comment: change your values variable intialization to `let values = new Set() `

Comment: could you tell me what would be the solution if it was an obj instead of array, for example if it was ```const obj ={ { pet:"cat" } , { pet:"cat" } , { pet:"cat" } , { pet:"dog" } }``` i just want obj.pet return "cat" once not 3 time

Comment: @Afra It sort of depends on other factors. 
If the other data that could be in these objects is unique and you are filtering duplicates it would look like `const obj = {cat: {type: "feline"}, dog: {type: "kanine"}}`.
If the other data is useful and you are accessing it by type often (finding all the dogs or something), then you might do `const obj = {cats: [{name: 'muffin'},{name: 'oreo'}], dogs: [{name: 'guss'}]}`